# Why does Cosmos DB show index utilization 0.00 % on an indexed property?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Can you tell why index utilization is 0.00 %?

I'm including this path in the indexing policy:

```
{
    "path": "/receivedDateTime/?",
    "indexes": [
        {
            "kind": "Range",
            "dataType": "Number",
            "precision": -1
        },
        {
            "kind": "Hash",
            "dataType": "String",
            "precision": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is an example of my documents:

```
{
    "id": "",
    "userId": "XYZ",
    ...
    "receivedDateTime": 635903262620000000,
    ...
}
```

When I run the following query I get zero index utilization.
Notes:

1. It does not happen with any other property/path that I included in
   the indexing policy
2. UserId is the partition key

   ```
   client.CreateDocumentQuery<Message>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseId, _collectionId),
                   new FeedOptions
                   {
                       PopulateQueryMetrics = true,
                       MaxItemCount = maxItemCount
                   })
               .Where(item => item.UserId == Guid.Parse("XYZ"))
               .OrderBy(m => m.ReceivedDateTime)
               .AsDocumentQuery();
   ```

[image]

On the other hand if I add `item.ReceivedDateTime >= 0` to the where clause I get 98.02 % of index utilization even when `item.ReceivedDateTime >= 0` is true for all the documents.

```
client.CreateDocumentQuery<Message>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_databaseId, _collectionId),
                    new FeedOptions
                    {
                        PopulateQueryMetrics = true,
                        MaxItemCount = maxItemCount
                    })
                .Where(item => item.UserId == Guid.Parse("XYZ") && item.ReceivedDateTime >= 0)
                .OrderBy(m => m.ReceivedDateTime)
                .AsDocumentQuery();
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Your where clause is filtering on an unindexed field.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT UserId (where clause filtering) is the partition key

Comment: Got it. That should be fine then.

Answer (score 0):

Like my other databases, the indexed properties are probably already ordered while storing. 
Hence using `OrderBy` wouldn't be as index intensive as actually doing a `Where` on it.

Here's a bit more on it, to give you a hint: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/order-query-results-with-azure-documentdb/

Comment: but see how it takes 909 RUs to process the query, when it should be close to 10 RUs. BTW, it only happens with that specific property, not with others, for example, not with `sentDateTime` which is of the same type, same everything...